# Dotcover doesn't report code coverage with MStests executing with Vstest.console

Tags: powershell, code-coverage, mstest, dotcover, vstest

Dotcover works fine if I use mstest.exe to generate code coverage, but mstest.exe doesn't work if my tests are using MSFakes. So I have no option but to use vstest.console.
      If I use Vstest.console it works fine with "MS tests with fakes" but reports code coverage as 0%. 
         Just to test i created another unit tests project where I am not using MSfakes, even for this project vstest.console reports code covegare as 0%.

I am using powershell script to automate unit and integration testing process. Below is my code. What am I missing here? or this feature not supported by dotcover?

```
$TestDlls = "D:\project.tests1\bin\Output\Org.Namespace.Domain.Project.Tests.dll","D:\project.tests\bin\output\Org.Namespace.Domain.Project.Tests.dll"
$MsTestExePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\Vstest.console.exe"
   $dotCoverExePath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\dotCover\v2.7\Bin\dotCover.exe"
   $snapshotFileName = "UnitTests.dcvr"     
   $WorkingDir = Get-Location
   $MsTestArgs =  $TestDlls + " /inIsolation /Platform:x64 /Framework:Framework45"

   exec { & $dotCoverExePath cover /TargetExecutable=$MsTestExePath /TargetArguments=$MsTestArgs /TargetWorkingDir=$WorkingDir /Output=$snapshotFileName }
```

Comment: This will probably not solve your problem but please use `Start-Process`. On how to run executables from powershell: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx